# Apply session id from request header

Tags: php, symfony

I am not sure if this is possible in Symfony so I came up with a question. The high-level scenario is:

1. A request on the API (built in Symfony) must return the **session-id** on the response body
2. The origin of request must include the returned **session-id** on its header for its succeeding request
3. The API must check if the request headers has the **session-id**, if it does it must set that session on the Symfony session

For testing purposes, I am using two REST client for browser instance:

- Postman (Chrome)
- HttpRequester (Firefox)

Here is the approach on code that I did:

The request from Postman:

```
POST http://path.domain/api/url/
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "key": "value"
}
```

Using HTTPFoundation Session, I set a session by:

```
$session = new Session();
$session->set('session-id', $session->getId());
$session->set('timestamp', time());
```

Then return it, here is the response:

```
200 OK
Content-Type:  application/json
{
    "session-id": "1a69f956b8efc5ab465356e3257a3230",
    "timestamp": 1487850859
}
```

Now, to simulate another response from different instance, I use HttpRequester but with the **session-id** on the header:

```
POST http://path.domain/api/url/
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "key": "value",
    "session-id": "1a69f956b8efc5ab465356e3257a3230"
}
```

By having a different request instance, I am expecting that Symfony will generate new session (new timestamp value). But for my case, I wanted to set the **session id** with the one in the request header, so I can access the previous **timestamp** as returned in the previous response.

I created a kernel event so I can intercept the request and do the checking if the request has **session-id** then do the setting of session.

```
// Get all PHP global variables
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

// Check if the request
if ($request->headers->has('session-id')) {
    $session = new Session();
    $session->setId($request->headers->get('session-id'));
}
```

However, if I do this I get the error:

```
"error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": [
      {
        "message": "Cannot change the ID of an active session",
        "class": "LogicException",
        ...
```

What did I miss? Is this possible?

Comment: Have you considered managing authentication via token as per [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/api_key_authentication.html) ? That is how I did authentication in my REST APIs.

Comment: Yeah, look into JWT Auth and Stateless Firewalls

Comment: There is a username in that, I don't need one. What I am just wanted is to have a flexibility to get the session from another instance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
if ($request->headers->has('session-id')) {
    $session = new Session();
    $session->start();

    $sess = $session->get('session-id');
    $session->set('session-id', $sess);
    ...
}
```

I saw in [the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html) there is a `get` function, but I normally don't use sessions so I don't know if this will work or not.

Can you try it?